# Transaction history data modeling in dynamo database

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I want to store transaction history in dynamo database. There are 2 suggested approaches given.

**Approach 1:** Transaction Ref -> Partition Key & GSI [CardNumber , TransactionDate]

**Approach 2 :** CardNumber -> Partition Key, Transaction Ref -> Range Key & LSI [CardNumber,TransactionDate]

I decided to go with the first one because I wanted to avoid hot partitioning.

Can any one please suggest a better approach or point in right direction.

Comment: In approach 2, why are you defining LSI ? Do you have any sorting requirement by transaction date ? Also please mention how will you access the data for most of the use cases? i.e. by transaction ref or card number ?

Comment: Data will be accessed by card number and date range.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with **approach 2 with slight modification**.

- CardNumber -> Partition Key
- TransactionDate -> Sort Key (I presume you can store the transaction 
  `timestamp` rather than just date)
- Transaction Ref -> Create GSI if needed (i.e. if you have any use case to get the data based on reference only)

**Reason:-**

The data model should satisfy the main use cases or query access patterns. In your approach 1, you would end up using GSI for the main use cases which is not a best practice to design a data model. We can use GSI for any alternate or edge cases.

Normally, the GSI should be synced immediately. However, in some rare scenarios, there could be some minor delay. Also, you should think whether you are going to use eventually consistent or consistent reads.

If you can avoid GSI, you can save cost as well.

Comment: Transaction date can not be sort key because it might be possible to get multiple transaction at the same time.[eg. when someone sending refund in terms of credit and you are doing transaction at the same time] but creating partition key as Card Number won't be suffering from "hot partitioning"? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Comment: @cody123 What would the preferred approach be instead of a creation date for the sort key? Just curious. Should you design your app not to create multiple transactions at the same time for the same card? Or should you instead use a transaction number for your sort key? Where each card gets their own count of transactions.

Comment: @IanSmith Correct. I checked one of the amazon services using dynamo in similar fashion.

Comment: @cody123 I also just learned about DDB key overloading. That seems to be the best practice for designing tables at scale.